# High Memory vs. Low Memory

Tags: memory, architecture, hardware

I have been reading over the last few days about assembly language, and the book keeps referring to high and low memory.

Is Low memory 0x00000000h and High memory 0xFFFFFFFFh? Or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is quite correct. If you have a certain memory-range, then values that are closer to 0 (or simply put closer to the 'beginning' of memory (aka. 1 - 2 GiB of 4 GiBs total)) are referred to as 'low memory'.